# How to have a data class (Kotlin) extend from a superclass and inherit one of the superclass fields?

Tags: kotlin, overriding, data-class

I try to create a custom toString() method for some of my data classes. But I would like to define the override of fun toString only once.

This would be my super class:

```
abstract class Id(val value: String) {
   override fun toString(): String {
       return value
   }
}
```

Now I want to use the customised toString() method in some of my data classes by extending the superclass Id:

```
data class MyId(val v: String): Id(v)
```

however, this would introduce a secondary field and getter for "v" in MyId, which is not what I want. Using "value" instead of "v" gives me the issue: 'value' hided a member of supertype 'Id'. I would like to reuse the "value" field and getter, defined in Id. I do not want to introduce a new one.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but you can do this

```
abstract class Id(open val value: String) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return value
    }
}

data class MyId(override val value: String): Id(value)
```

Comment: thank you indeed. The key here is was opening the value in the superclass. You see, I am quite new to Kotlin, and I do not have the reflex yet to explicit open up class members I need in the subclasses. (In java, class members are open by default.) And then, I was also confused by the syntax that at the same time, defines two class member (value + getter), and defines a constructor argument + the fact that I need to open it up

Comment: clarified intention in the question

Comment: this does not help: the data class itself introduces a toString() implementation, overriding the one of the superclass. In the example, (MyId("avalue").toString()) would result in string "MyId("avalue")" and NOT "avalue"

Answer (score 1):

Note that for non-`data` classes, you could just remove `val` instead of overriding it:

```
class MyId(value: String): Id(value)
```

This also doesn't require `value` in `Id` to be `open`.

This isn't legal when `MyId` is a data class because all of its constructor parameters must be `val` or `var`.

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to do in my question was overriding the toString() method of a data class, by exsting a superclass.

This is not possible. Francesc his solution would not override the toString() method of the dataclass. The generated toString method of the dataclass would still be used.

consider:

```
  val myId = MyId("a string value")
  assertThat(myId.toString()).isEqualTo("MyId\"a string value\")")
  assertThat(myId.toString()).isNotEqualTo("a string value")
```

The only way of altering the `.toString()` method of a data class, is in the data class itself:

```
data class MyId(val value: String) {
  override fun toString() = value
}
```